# Trying to get property 'resource' of non-object in PaginatedResourceResponse.php after Laravel-update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-collection, laravel-resource

actually I am getting this error after updating Laravel from v7.5.1 to v7.6.2

```
"message": "Trying to get property 'resource' of non-object",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/Json/PaginatedResourceResponse.php",
    "line": 29,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/Json/PaginatedResourceResponse.php",
            "line": 29,
            "function": "handleError",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "function": "Illuminate\\Http\\Resources\\Json\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Resources\\Json\\PaginatedResourceResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php",
            "line": 638,
            "function": "array_map"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php",
            "line": 23,
            "function": "map",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Support\\Collection",
            "type": "->"
        },
```

This is what causes the error:

```
$products = Product::findMany($array)->paginate(10);
//dump($products);

/*Create ResourceCollection*/
return new ProductResourceCollection($products);
```

The dump returns this:

```
------------ ----------------------------------------------- 
  date         Thu, 16 Apr 2020 08:53:53 +0000                
  controller   "ProductApiController"                         
  source       ProductApiController.php on line 56            
  file         app/Http/Controllers/ProductApiController.php  
 ------------ ----------------------------------------------- 

Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator^ {#300
  #total: 1
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection^ {#319
    #items: array:1 [
      0 => App\Product^ {#400
        #casts: array:9 [
          "category" => "object"
        ]
        #connection: null
        #table: "products"
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #with: []
        #withCount: []
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: true
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #attributes: array:21 [
          "id" => "1"
          "title" => "Test"
          "category" => "{"id":1,"title":"Test","slug":null}"
        ]
        #original: array:21 [
          "id" => "1"
          "title" => "Test"
          "category" => "{"id":1,"title":"Test","slug":null}"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  #perPage: 10
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://example.org/api/product/pluck/1,2,3"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +onEachSide: 3
  #options: array:2 [
    "path" => "http://example.org/api/product/pluck/1,2,3"
    "pageName" => "page"
  ]
}
```

This is the resource:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'current_page'   => $this->resource->currentPage(),
        'first_page_url' => $this->resource->url(1),
        'from'           => $this->resource->firstItem(),
        'last_page'      => $this->resource->lastPage(),
        'last_page_url'  => $this->resource->url($this->lastPage()),
        'next_page_url'  => $this->resource->nextPageUrl(),
        'per_page'       => $this->resource->perPage(),
        'prev_page_url'  => $this->resource->previousPageUrl(),
        'to'             => $this->resource->lastItem(),
        'total'          => $this->resource->total(),
        'data'           => $this->collection->transform(function ($product
        ) {
            return [
                'id'                => $product->id,
                'title'             => $product->title,
                'category'          => $product->category,
            ];
        }),
    ];
}
```

If I comment `'data'=> $this->collection->transform(function ($product) {` the error does not appear... But... Well, then the app does not work ;-)

### My question

So my question is: Is this way of modifying data incorrect and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/32296 .

At the moment I can do something like

```
$this->collectResource($this->collection)
                ->transform(...)
```

which solves the problem.